# I just want to know whether these two sentence are correct and are giving the same meaning

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. Admission of defeat without doing hard work will make you face many problem.
> 2. Admitting  defeat without doing hard work will make you face many problem.

Comment: I think you were downvoted because the question is difficult to understand. What are you trying to say? Are you saying that you must work hard? Are you saying that if you give up without trying that you will not accomplish much?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do mean the same thing, though the constructions are "foreign-sounding", and "problem" should be "problem**s**".

The reason they are "foreign-sounding" is that "make you face" is usually understood to mean "deal with", and I suspect you really meant "make you endure" or "cause you to suffer".  "Endure" and "suffer" are things one does **passively**, whereas "deal with" is an **active** response.

Native speakers would probably say something like

> Admitting defeat **without having worked hard** [to deal with/solve the problem] **first** will **cause** [the person, you, her, etc] **many problems** [later in life].

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, "many" is a plural adjective, so you want to say either "face many problem**s**," or "face **a** problem."

In your first example, "admission of defeat" would require the article, "the" to make it grammatically correct, but the resulting sentence is awkward and I wouldn't use it.

> **The** admission of defeat without doing hard work will make you face many problems.

The second example is much better, but still sounds awkward. I would replace "make you face" with "cause you."

> Admitting defeat without doing hard work will cause you many problemss.

Comment: Or "An admission of defeat". I think you can say, "Admission of defeat without  having first done the work, will cause (many) problems."

Comment: @WillowRex There are **many** different ways to express this idea, and your suggestion is a good one. I was just trying to stick to the OP's original wording as much as possible to avoid confusion and only address the grammatical errors.

Comment: agreed -- and I added one... ;)

Comment: I believe you can say the first sentence with or without **the** or **an** at the beginning.  It is not imperative to use either of them